# How can I make my dynamic drop-down list be dependent dependent also to parent drop down?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a dependent drop-down list. The `sub_cat` is dependent on `parent_cat`

at the same time it is dynamic also, where user can add additional if needed.

And my problem starts here, Drop down dependent is already working, where the second drop-down `sub_cat` is dependent to what is selected in the first drop-down `parent_cat`.
but, when I click `Add Process` (add additional) `sub_cat`.
sub_cat is now empty.

How can I make it work that if I click add process, the sub_cat will be populated also depends on what is selected in parent_cat.

here's my code:
index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loadScript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynamic.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="GET" action="input.php">
        <label for="category">Parent Category</label>
         <?php
          echo'<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">';
          while($row = $query_parent->fetch()) {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['w_id'].'">' . $row['wafer_type'] . '</option>'; 
          }
          echo '</select>';
         ?>
     <br/>
         <?php
          require 'second_dd.php';
         ?>
     <input type="button" name="add_item" value="Add Process  " onClick="addMore()" />
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit">      
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

second_dd.php

```
<div id="product">
    <select name="sub_cat[]" id="sub_cat"></select>
</div>
```

loadsubcat.php

```
<?php 
include 'db/pdo-connect.php';

$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM process WHERE wafer_id = {$parent_cat}");
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['p_id'].'">' . $row['process_name'] . '</option>'; 
    }
?>
```

loadscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
```

dynamic.js - this is for adding second dropdown list.

```
function addMore() {
    $("<div>").load("second_dd.php", function() {
            $("#product").append($(this).html());
    }); 
}
```

> my DB goes like this:

parent_cat

```
id, category
```

sub_cat

```
id, category_id, sub_category
```

Answer (score 0):

What does file `dynamic.php` do ?

The selector `$("<div>")` is not right which cannot find any element, and `.load` function wont execute the script. just load the file content.

Comment: Hi Bandon, Sorry I changed it to `second_dd.php` instead of `dynamic.php` . since there's dynamic.js to avoid confusion.